# Pressing Ctrl + S automatically opens Output window

Tags: visual-studio-2012, output-window

Whenever i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> from keyboard or whenever i click on any file in Solution Explorer it automatically opens output window only in `Visual Studio 2012`.

I tried

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Show output window when build starts

I am using `Visual Studio Professional 2012`

But its just not working. Its irritates a lot. Please suggest how to get rid of it.

Comment: Did you check how 'Ctrl+S' is assigned in 'Tools -> Options -> Keyboard'?

Comment: Yup checked...its assigned to `Save` ...

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell ... maybe some plugIns installed which can ocur the problem?

Comment: Well its a fresh VS installation and i am sure there is no plugin installed at all...

Comment: And 'Ctrl-Alt-O' also opens the output window? Very straingh for a fresh installation. Did you try a 'Reset' in 'Options -> Keyboard'?

Comment: No..i believe it doesn't belongs to Keyboard settings....it also gets opened if clicked any file in Solution Explorer...

Comment: Hi, @MayankPathak thanks for asking. Can you please share the solution, if you got it? I am also facing the same issue back from a few days.

Answer (score 1):

if someone is facing this issue in visual studio community 2015, in my case the issue was caused because of the use of **Backup and sync utility from google**, I have synced my source directory to my google drive to maintain the latest copy of source backed up.

The backup utility locks the file which you might be editing for syncing it to cloud storage. since the file is locked by another process, the visual studio cannot save the changes in the file.

The fix was to pause the syncing for the time you are doing frequent changes.
In your case, it might be some other process which might be locking the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an extension, one of them could be the reason.

I had the same problem while saving the CMakeLists.txt files. I checked one of the extension's setting, "CMake Tools", it has a **"Cmake: Reveal Log"** settings which causing this problem. I simply deactivated it

[image: CMake Tools Extension Settings]

I suggest you to check extensions' settings or try to find on settings with searching "output", "focus" etc.